# React native Card horizontal scrollView and/or FlatList

Tags: react-native

Good day I've been trying to create a scroll for my Card which contains a 4 grid of Images.
The Card is fine but the scrollView makes everything horizontal
Do you suggest I import Card from React-Native-element?

`     {

```
 import {Card} from 'react-native-elements'
 export default class App extends Component{
 render(){
    return(
             <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                         <Card  >

                          {
                                <View style={styles.card}>....</View>
                              }
                         </Card>
                      </ScrollView>
      );
         }
           }
```

`

Comment: Please share some code of what you tried

Comment: `  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                          <Card  >

                              {
                                    <View>
                                    <View style={styles.card}>...
                                    </View>
                                  </View>
                              }
                                  
                          </Card>
                          </ScrollView>`

Comment: What is the CSS for `styles.card` ? and why `horizontal={true}` ?

Comment: `card: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
  }`

Comment: I set `horizontal = {true}` to get an horizontal `ScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is, you have multiple images and you need to arrange 4 images in a row then wrap and again 4 in the next row so on and so forth.

So I suggest **flatlist**. Try the below code,

```
renderCard = item => {
  <Card image={item} />
}

render() {
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={(item) => this.renderCard(item)}
    horizontal={false}
    noOfColumns={4}
  />
}
```

Comment: Thanks all I had to do was to put my card into a container which has a fixed height and width, then I passed the container into my ScrollView which then viewed it as one variable. When ever I pass anything to the container it renders alrught.